# NSColorWell changing text color

Tags: macos, nscolorwell

I'm using `NSColorWell` in my app to change background color. However it changes text color in my `NSTextView` as well. I don't want it to change text color. How can I disable it? I just want to use it as a color picker form my background color.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean.  I think you're talking about the `NSColorPanel` interacting with the `NSTextView` in addition to the `NSColorWell` you're using for the background color—am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I have NSColorWell which by default opens NSColorPanel, after changing color in color panel it changes text color in NSTextView as well

Comment: @Wojtek I am looking around how to use two `NSColorWell` one for text color and second one for background color. How did you make NSColorWell for background color and have you solved the problem with automatic, by default, change the text color?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is that when your `NSTextView` is the first responder it's accidentally collecting the color picker's `changeColor(_:)` action.  The easiest thing to do that I can think of right now is to subclass `NSTextView` and override `changeColor(_:)` to do nothing at all.

Comment: I already tried that, the problem is that I use NSFontPanel as well, and there's option to change text color, which is desired. I just want the second NSColorPanel to be used for changing background color of the window (but it automatically changes text as well)